# RDLC Expression shows #Error

Tags: rdlc

My writing an Expression RDLC SSRS

```
((Sum(Fields!MockObtMarks.Value))/(Sum(Fields!MockTotalMarks.Value))) * 100
```

Now this expression shows #Error when the sum (0/0) *100

i have used if and switch case still not working

Answer (score 0):

You should really show the expressions you tried in your question, but this should do:

```
=IIF( (Sum(Fields!MockTotalMarks.Value)) = 0, 0,  ((Sum(Fields!MockObtMarks.Value))/(Sum(Fields!MockTotalMarks.Value))) * 100 )
```